# Exporting VueJS-rendered HTML with checkbox fails to preserve checked state

Tags: html, checkbox, vue.js, vue-component

My component template contains the following checkbox code:

```
<div ref="htmlData">
    <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        class="mycb" 
        :id="uniqID" 
        :disabled="disabled"
        v-model="cbvalue"
    >
</div>
```

(parts removed for simplicity).

I need to create a PDF out of this template (on server). This is what i'm doing in the code:

```
methods : {
    save () {
        let saveData = {
              'html': this.$refs.htmlData.innerHTML 
            };
        this.$http.post('/api/save',saveData);
    }
}
```

However, the saved HTML doesn't contain checkbox state, so it always saves an unchecked checkbox.

Here's a slightly modified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/3532/).

**My question is**: how can I capture the checkbox state in the rendered HTML?

I tried adding `:checked="cbvalue"` prop - no luck

Comment: I have 2 questions for you, First Why you pushing HTML to server ? Second  VueJS state is with Virtual DOM, http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/3533/ i have modified something you will not see my name with input type text as well .. my suggestion will be push JSON data to server , use template to bind your data.

Comment: 1. i need to convert html to pdf and i don't know a good JS library that can do it on the client side. 2. i want to avoid any other parsing on the server since the HTML templates can vary. some use checkboxes, some don't, and I don't want to install a full server-side-rendering engine to solve this small problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there's no way to bind the `checked` attribute of an input; Vue does everything through the property. (For reference, the property is the internal state, the attribute is what shows up in the HTML.)

To get the attribute to reflect the property, you can add a little directive.

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: () => ({
    val: false
  }),
  methods: {
    save() {
      console.log(this.$refs.main.innerHTML);
    }
  },
  directives: {
    explicitChecked: {
      update(el) {
        if (el.checked) {
          el.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
          el.removeAttribute('checked');
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button @click="save">save</button>
  <div ref="main">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="val" v-explicit-checked>
  </div>
</div>
```